# Accurate least-squares fit algorithm needed

Tags: algorithm, least-squares

I've experimented with the two ways of implementing a least-squares fit (LSF) algorithm shown [here](http://www.johndcook.com/blog/2008/10/20/comparing-two-ways-to-fit-a-line-to-data/).

The first code is simply the textbook approach, as described by Wolfram's page on LSF. The second code re-arranges the equation to minimize machine errors. Both codes produce similar results for my data. I compared these results with Matlab's p=polyfit(x,y,1) function, using correlation coefficients to measure the "goodness" of fit and compare each of the 3 routines. I observed that while all 3 methods produced good results, at least for my data, Matlab's routine had the best fit (the other 2 routines had similar results to each other).

Matlab's p=polyfit(x,y,1) function uses a Vandermonde matrix, V (n x 2 matrix) and QR factorization to solve the least-squares problem. In Matlab code, it looks like:

```
V = [x1,1; x2,1; x3,1; ... xn,1]  % this line is pseudo-code
[Q,R] = qr(V,0);
p = R\(Q'*y);      % performs same as p = V\y
```

I'm not a mathematician, so I don't understand why it would be more accurate. Although the difference is slight, in my case I need to obtain the slope from the LSF and multiply it by a large number, so any improvement in accuracy shows up in my results.

For reasons I can't get into, I cannot use Matlab's routine in my work. So, I'm wondering if anyone has a more accurate equation-based approach recommendation I could use that is an improvement over the above two approaches, in terms of rounding errors/machine accuracy/etc.

Any comments appreciated! thanks in advance.

Comment: QR is a stable way to solve systems of equations. If your data is close to degenerate, SVD is probably a better way to go (albeit more expensive computationally). Least square problems should never be dealt with naively, as you showed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a polynomial fitting, you can create a [Vandermonde](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix) matrix and solve the linear system, as you already done.

Another solution is using methods like [Gauss-Newton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Newton_algorithm) to fit the data (since the system is linear, one iteration should do fine). There are differences between the methods. One possibly reason is the [Runge's phenomenon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge%27s_phenomenon).

Comment: Thanks, Would Gauss-Newton be any more accurate than least-squares fit? I wouldn't think I'd see Runge's phenomenon since I'm only modeling as y=mx+b (1st order).

Comment: I didn't saw the first order, sorry. But how are you measuring the accuracy? Just comparing the results with Matlab?

Comment: I'm looking at the correlation coefficient resulting from each method, and assuming higher correlation indicates a more accurate fit to the data (e.g. smaller least-squares error).